# 'ngb-rating' is not a known element

Tags: ng-bootstrap

Installed via

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

NgbModule imported

```
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 
imports: [NgbModule ]
```

added a component

```
<ngb-rating [max]="5" [(rate)]="starRating" [readonly]="false"></ngb-rating>
```

Error returned

```
'ngb-rating' is not a known element:
```

Change to only import the component

```
import { NgbRating} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 
imports: [NgbRating ]
```

Error returned

```
Type NgbRating does not have 'ɵmod' property.
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems changing

```
import { NgbRating} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 
imports: [NgbRating ]
```

to

```
import { NgbRatingModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap'; 
imports: [NgbRatingModule ]
```

Fixed the problem